# Assistive touch Laggy with Tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

Hi I have a simple Tableview with custom Xib  on my first page but the Assistive Touch becomes laggy when the tableview is filled , its not in other pages with no tableview , and the tableview itself is not laggy on scrolling and It has only 5 rows

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    print("tableview Called")
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TransactionsListCell") as!TransactionsListCell
    cell.tag = indexPath.row
    let cellClicked = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector (self.CellClicked(sender:)))
    cell.addGestureRecognizer(cellClicked)
    return cell
}
```

and I've registered the tableview nib in viewdidload like below :

```
 TransactionTable.register(UINib(nibName:"TransactionsListCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier:"TransactionsListCell")
```

and the cell is so simple containing one image and 4 labels and the I even tried with not configuring the cell (no loading any image and texts ) but no results .
thanks for your help

Comment: @AdityaSrivastava that wasn't the problem , I even tried removing that line too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem was caused by a Library I was using to Create Circled UIImageViews Called "SwiftyAvatar" , removing it solved the problem .